# Kinda stuck with this "end of line without continuation error". What am i missing here?

Tags: pine-script

It's giving me the error on the last line.

```
arn = input(1.007, title="Take Profit")

carv = hv > 20

if carv ? arn = 1.03 : na

lim = high > (upper*arn)
```

Comment: I get an error at `if carv ? arn = 1.03 : na`. Maybe copy your whole code?

Answer (score 1):

Your code gives an error at this line `if carv ? arn = 1.03 : na`.

It does not make any sense, you probably want something like:

```
arn := carv ? 1.03 : na
```

Comment: Thanks! I did end up figuring it out soon after posting this but I forgot to delete it